# Creating a JSON array

Tags: c#, json

I am new to JSON. I am trying to create below JSON format using C#:

```
series: {
   name: "series1",
   data: [[0,2],[1,3],[2,1],[3,4]]
}
```

I am struggling with the `data` part. What should be my .NET code to achieve the above format?

Comment: How is the data stored in your C# code? What have you tried?

Comment: Well for starters that is not correct Json

Comment: You can also use [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) to achieve this. It is a popular library for working with Json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<int[]> arr = new List<int[]>()
    {
        new[]{0,2},new[]{1,3},new[]{2,1},new[]{3,4},
    };

var obj = new { data = arr };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

**OUTPUT:** `{"data":[[0,2],[1,3],[2,1],[3,4]]}`

#### OR

declare these classes (see http://json2csharp.com/)

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Series series { get; set; }
}

public class Series
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> data { get; set; }
}
```

create an instance of `RootObject`, fill the properties, and serialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Use newtonsoft Json.net to serialize the objects, available via nuget or http://james.newtonking.com/json

Create the objects like this

```
var seriesContent = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"name", "series1"},
    {"data", new[] {new[]{0,2},new[]{1,3},new[]{2,1},new[]{3,4}}}
};

var series = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"series", seriesContent}
};

var s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(series);
```

`s` will contain

```
{
    "series": {
        "name": "series1",
        "data": [
            [0, 2],
            [1, 3],
            [2, 1],
            [3, 4]
        ]
    }
}
```